# Cannot use import statement outside a module even in ESM

Tags: typescript, next.js, babeljs, vite, es6-modules

so I have an application which relies on a library which we have published on NPM. When importing this library in a freshly created NextJs application throws the following.

```bash
error - /Users/apple/testing-build/node_modules/foobar/dist/some-library.es.js:1
import t, { useState as M } from "react";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1094:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1129:27)
...
```

We're using Node 18.13.0.

Now I have already tried a lot of things, I changed my application type to module. I changed the library's type to module and did the same try with CJS on both end.

The library itself is written in TypeScript and uses ESM and compiled down to TypeScript. Here is the `tsconfig.json` for the library:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*.*"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

And here is what we have got on our end where the package itself is being utilized!

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5", // Also tried with `ESNext`
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I tried to see the dist code the library was generating it was the following (Removed middle part).

```js
// Beginning parts imports the libraries required
import t, { useState as D } from "react";
import l, { css as r } from "styled-components";
import { generateMedia as R } from "styled-media-query";

// ....

// The Ending part exports the components
export {
  ot as Accordian,
  Le as Badge,
  K as Button,
  nt as Card,
  lt as CollapsibleText,
  ct as Header,
  at as If
};
```

As you can see the library itself exports in ESM way. And the one using it imports in the ESM way. Any help here is much appreciated! Thanks.

EDIT: We're using Babel and Vite to transpile the package here are the configurations.

````js
import { resolve } from 'node:path';

import { defineConfig, loadEnv, splitVendorChunkPlugin } from 'vite';
import { externalizeDeps } from 'vite-plugin-externalize-deps';
import nodeResolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import * as pkg from './package.json';

/**
 * Verify if the envs sent by the user were correct.
 * Throws if not valid!
 *
 * @param {string} mode Default mode exposed by Vite
 */
function verifyEnv(mode: string): boolean {
  switch (mode) {
    // Fallthrough and return the name env
    case 'test':
    case 'local':
    case 'production':
    case 'dev': {
      return true;
    }

    case 'development': {
      throw new Error(
        'Seems like you provided mode as `development` means you probably wanted to use `dev` which is another script. Prefer our script over `vite dev`.'
      );
    }

    default: {
      throw new Error(
        `Either you provided an incorrect environment or you didn't send anything. Env received was ${process.env.NODE_ENV}.`
      );
    }
  }
}

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  verifyEnv(mode);
  const appEnv = loadEnv(mode, `${process.cwd()}/.env.${mode}`);

  return {
    /**
     * Build options for Vite, these also contain information about
     * rollup that vite uses under the hood.
     */
    build: {
      outDir: 'dist',

      /**
       * These are options passed as they are to rollup under the hood
       */
      rollupOptions: {
        input: './src/index.ts',

        /**
         * This is experimental with Rollup and enables optimizations on
         * the rollup treeshaking algorithm. It supports `smallest`, `recommended`,
         * and `safest`. We will try with smallest if it breaks something we
         * should go with `recommended`.
         *
         * @see https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#treeshake
         */
        treeshake: 'smallest',

        /**
         * To import libraries that are compiled we need to make sure that we
         * are able to support both CJS and module syntax.
         * The NodeResolve and Commonjs help with that.
         */
        plugins: [nodeResolve({ mainFields: ['module', 'main'], browser: true }), commonjs()],
        output: {
          /**
           * We need to explicitly mention our dependencies and peerDependencies.
           * This will let rollup know that these dependencies are the ones that we
           * are including in our code.
           *
           * The `pkg` points to the `package.json` file and scans whatever we've mentioned
           * in `dependencies` and `peerDependencies`. The problem here is that we require
           * `react` and other dependencies to run this properly on development and storybooks
           * but in the final build this is not required.
           *
           * As of right now we don't have any `peerDependencies` however at the time we include
           * them we need to add `...pkg.peerDependencies` here too!
           */
          globals: {
            ...pkg.dependencies
          }
        }
      },

      /**
       * This will keep in note that the files that you export in your build
       * will be compatible with both the `require` and `import` statement.
       *
       * @example
       * The following two files will be generated!
       *
       * - foo-components.es.js
       * - foo-components.umd.js
       *
       * This allows the following:
       * ```js
       * // Automatically references ES build
       * import { Button } from 'foo-components';
       * ```
       *
       * @see https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode
       */
      lib: {
        entry: resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/index.ts'),
        name: 'Foo Components',
        formats: ['es', 'umd'],
        fileName: (format) => `foo-components.${format}.js`
      }
    },

    /**
     * We use aliases in our project that is natively mapped by TypeScript
     * However for the transpilation to happen those aliases MUST also be
     * also be defined for Vite.
     */
    resolve: {
      alias: [
        { find: '@src', replacement: resolve(__dirname, './src') },
        { find: '@utils', replacement: resolve(__dirname, './src/utils') },
        { find: '@themes', replacement: resolve(__dirname, './src/themes') },
        { find: '@components', replacement: resolve(__dirname, './src/components') },
        { find: '@dlsCss', replacement: resolve(__dirname, './src/design/dls.min.css') }
      ]
    },

    /**
     * These are plugins that can be plugged into Vite to extend support
     */
    plugins: [
      /**
       * Plugin to support React
       */
      react({
        // Exclude storybook stories
        exclude: /\.stories\.(t|j)sx?$/,

        // Support both TS and TSX files
        include: ['./src/**/*.tsx', './src/**/*.ts'],

        // Use babel.config.js
        babel: { configFile: true }
      }),

      /**
       * This will automatically generate a `d.ts` file for you.
       * This is helpful for people using JavsScript
       */
      dts({
        include: ['./src/components']
      }),

      /**
       * This will handle chunking if you introduce any vendor.
       */
      splitVendorChunkPlugin(),

      /**
       * The dependencies that we are importing in our project are not
       * to be packaged since they will be listed as peerDepencies and
       * should be marked external.
       */
      externalizeDeps()
    ],

    /**
     * Define enviornmental variables for your project
     */
    define: {
      __APP_ENV__: appEnv
    }
  };
});
````

And here is the babel config

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          browsers: ['> 0.25%, not dead']
        },
        modules: false,
        corejs: '3.6.5',
        useBuiltIns: 'entry'
      }
    ],
    '@babel/preset-react',
    '@babel/preset-typescript'
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-optional-chaining',
    'styled-components',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import'
  ],
  env: {
    production: {
      only: ['app'],
      plugins: [
        'transform-react-remove-prop-types',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements'
      ]
    },
    test: {
      plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
        'dynamic-import-node',
        [
          'auto-import',
          {
            declarations: [{ default: 'React', path: 'react' }]
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: `"noEmit": true` - are you sure it's typescript that is generating the broken modules?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Bergi  actually we're using Vite to bundle it together I am updating my question with the Vite and Babel config we're using.

Comment: what is your default type in package.json?

Comment: @JorgeGuerreiro the default `package.json` doesn't have any `type` property defined however I tried changing it to `"type": "module"` that too throws!